# How can I get the node name where the upstream job has run in the downstream job in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have multiple nodes with 'build_run' label (Eg; node1, node2 , node3). So when I run this pipeline I can't be sure that 'Build' and 'Run' job has run in same node. 'Build' can happen in 'node1' and 'Run' can happen in 'node3'. I want both Build and run happen in the same node. But I don't want to hard code the same.
I want to know which node has picke up by 'Build'. So that I can pass it as a node parameter to Run.
How can I solve this?

```
stage('Build, run) {
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        def builds = { 
            stage('Build') {
                build job: 'Build', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'TestMachine', label: 'build_run']]
            }

            stage('Run') {
               build job: 'Run', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'TestMachine', label: 'build_run']]
            }
        }
    }
}
parallel builds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used something like below and it worked for me. (Used rawBuild.getEnvironment()['NODE_NAME'] to get the node in which the job has run.)

```
    def node_to_use = ""
    stage('Build, run) {
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
            def builds = { 
                stage('Build') {
                    def build_var = build job: 'Build', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'TestMachine', label: 'build_run']]
                    node_to_use = build_var.rawBuild.getEnvironment()['NODE_NAME']
                }

                stage('Run') {
                   build job: 'Run', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'TestMachine', label: node_to_use]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    parallel builds
```